# unable to look up https (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known) on git pull request

Tags: git, macos, github, gitlab

I'm trying to setup a remote repository on my macbook. Went through the regular git steps, setup the remote repository, name, email, logon and whatnot. When I run `git remote -v`, my origins and upstreams are ok, I even made it to clone the repository.

The issue is when I try to make a pull or a push I got this error: unable to look up https (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

Anyone knows whats going on?

Answer (score 4):

try this command :

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/
```

Comment: There's no evidence the OP is using github in the original question nor an explanation of why this is the right solution nor what's going on.